# Why after change Timezone NSTimeZone return old Timezone

Tags: objective-c, nstimezone

I minimize to tray my app, then change Timezone and then open app NSTimeZone return old value for time zone. 
If I  minimize to tray and open again Timezone return new value. How can I fix it?

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(reloadVC)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                               object:nil];
-(void) reloadVC{
    NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    NSLog(@"%@", currentTimeZone);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you're planning to do on entering the foreground is catch the timezone change, observe this notification instead: [`NSSystem​Time​Zone​Did​Change​Notification`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nssystemtimezonedidchangenotification)

This notification is queued to be processed when your app enters the foreground, so you don't need a separate observer for entering the foreground.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(reloadVC)
                                             name:NSSystem​Time​Zone​Did​Change​Notification
                                           object:nil];
-(void) reloadVC{
    NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    NSLog(@"%@", currentTimeZone);
}
```